# PostgreSQL backend behavior upon receiving "Terminate" ('X') after "COMMIT"

Tags: postgresql, erlang

We run a postgres server v9.2.8, and use epgsql (erlang) as a client library. And in some cases, which we had on production but weren't able to reproduce in dev environment, we're loosing data.

A function in our application (it should be killed) allows an operator to change session parameters on a running connection. Since connection is usually always busy on production, a "SET SESSION bla-bla" query always crashes pgsql_connection process.

Before crashing, pgsql_connection sends a "Terminate" ('X') signal via pgsql_sock (a wrapper around tcp socket) to a backend. At the same time another erlang process (let's call it "worker") is waiting for a response from postgres backend using the same socket.

Now the question: is it possible that upon receiving a "Terminate" signal from a client, backend can cancel last transaction even if it has sent an "OK" on "COMMIT" statement already?

Because if it **is** possible, a worker will have a chance to report to the main application process about successfully written transaction while indeed the transaction has been cancelled.

Or, where can I read more details about this? Documentation says (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/protocol-flow.html):

> For either normal or abnormal termination, any open transaction is
>   rolled back, not committed. One should note however that if a frontend
>   disconnects while a non-SELECT query is being processed, the backend
>   will probably finish the query before noticing the disconnection. If
>   the query is outside any transaction block (BEGIN ... COMMIT sequence)
>   then its results might be committed before the disconnection is
>   recognized.

– not a crystal clear statement.

Comment: I don't see why the documentation isn't crystal clear. It roughly says: "The database is always in a consistent state". Your question however could be clearer I think. Consider marking it up with some markup so it is easier to read.

Comment: It could be better with definitions for "probably" and "might be".

Comment: @Ivan The problem is that it's not 100% determinate, because you're taking the interaction of a hard transactional system (Pg) and a non-transactional system (TCP/IP with a client). To get around it would require a persistent, crash-safe client-side transaction log too.

Comment: Which fork of `epgsql` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> Now the question: is it possible that upon receiving a "Terminate" signal from a client, backend can cancel last transaction even if it has sent an "OK" on "COMMIT" statement already?

No. that is fundamentally impossible. If it's committed, it's committed, and there's no going back. That's what "commit" means.

The only time Pg might return success before the commit hits disk and is persistent is if you told it to by setting `synchronous_commit = off`.

If you're seeing anything different happening then most likely it's a result of attempting to share a single connection between multiple processes (as you establish the connection before `fork()`) without proper locking or other mutual exclusion to ensure that the connection is locked while a command is in-flight.

Note that the reverse isn't true, which might be what you're thinking of with the quoted documentation passage. A transaction *can* get committed without returning a successful OK to the client if the client goes away (crashes, loses connection, etc) after issuing the commit command.

---

What the application is doing, where it sends out-of-sync messages on the wire protocol, is totally broken. It's guaranteed to cause unpredictable problems. The protocol is somewhat robust, so you're not likely to get things like an unintended `commit`, but you're very likely to get transactions aborted or whole sessions disconnected suddenly.

---

If you need to be able to roll back/abort committed transactions, then your application design has problems. You're not really ready to commit when you say `COMMIT`. You would have the same problem if the app process crashed or the whole server crashed between Pg committing the transaction and you doing whatever you need to do.

If you cannot fix the app design to avoid this then you will have to use two-phase transactions, either directly using `PREPARE TRANSACTION` then `COMMIT PREPARED`, or indirectly via the XA API. This has significant costs in performance and management overhead, but it's the only option if you need to do special work after database commit but before you're really "done".

The docs you quote are talking about the case where the app has sent a `COMMIT` but then disconnects before receiving the backend's acknowledgement of the commit. Because TCP/IP is buffered there's no guarantee the `COMMIT` got flushed to Pg, and if it did there's no guarantee it doesn't accompany the `RST` that terminates the connection. So in this specific case it's somewhat uncertain whether the transaction will commit or not. An application for which this is a problem would need to have a way of checking whether the last unit of work committed or not when it resumes work, or if it can't do that use two-phase transactions. The docs you quote say nothing about being able to cancel a commit after it's completed, because you can't. Ever.

Assuming that the app has to do some kind of extra work after commit, like moving a file or sending an email or doing work on another data store, then you're probably going to need two-phase transactions. Even then you're vulnerable to issues unless *all parties in the distributed transaction* support two phase commit, because your "other bit" could get done then your worker or server could crash before the confirmation of its completion is sent to the database to finish phase II of the commit.

You can keep your own two phase commit log of sorts in the DB instead of using true 2PC:

1. Do the main database work and write a record to the work log table that says "I've done the work in the database and I'm about to do the next part".
2. Do the next part; and
3. Update the work log to say the next part is done.

... but this has the same problem, where a crash between parts 2 and 3 causes the app to forget that it did part 2 and repeat it on startup. If you can't live with that, you need to find a way to make part 2 commit completion verifiable, so you can tell if it's done or not, or find a way to make it capable of doing 2-phase commit.

To learn more about this topic, read about XA, distributed transactions, two-phase commit, etc.

Comment: thanks, but that's not what my application wants.<br/>
No offense to postgres, I love it. And it's not only about committed or not committed.<br/>
Problem with my application is that it's possible to send commands to the same postgres backend from different erlang processes. E.g. a signal from postgres backend triggered by a command from another process can put my application and/or client library to an unexpected state. I want more details on how postgres backends works in this scenario in order to fix this properly on my side.

Comment: @Ivan There's one backend per connection, and connections are per-process. The only way you could do what I think you're describing is if you connect to PostgreSQL then `fork()` without `exec()`. If you do that, you're courting disaster because the client library (libpq) does *not* permit multiple threads to use the same connection at the same time. It'll work if the threads are isolated with proper mutexes, but probably won't work if you're using separate processes instead because any internal libpq state will get out of sync. Just don't do that. It's broken. It cannot be made safe.

Comment: my application is in erlang, it's **very** easy to use the same connection from another process. I'd like to fix this so that nobody will be able to send any commands to a backend from another process, even if one get access to a connection pid.

Comment: @Ivan Does the Earlang database adapter for PostgreSQL wrap libpq? Or is it a competely separate implementation (like PgJDBC is)?

Comment: @Ivan ... or, after a quick Google search, rather "which Erlang driver for PostgreSQL are you using"? [`epgsql`](https://github.com/wg/epgsql)? `epg` (a libpq wrapper)? One of the numerous others? Anyway, unless it's designed to share a connection safely, with proper synchronisation, then connecting before fork() is probably wrong.

Comment: epgsql, I wrote this on the first line.

Comment: @Ivan I'm blind. Sorry. I'm quite certain that the driver doesn't synchronise between processes correctly (otherwise you couldn't have the described error) though. What I wrote above covers what you were asking about being able to confirm a transaction then still roll it back (no, it can't). I think you're now mixing two different things - the committed/uncommitted issue in your original question, and separate issues with inter-process synchronisation while sharing a common connection established before fork().

Comment: @Ivan Answer revised, see before the cut.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts. I got the point about "if it's committed, it's committed", and I know myself that working with a connection from different processes is bad (as I stated in the question, the api function allowing this should be killed). And that the issue I have is because an operator issues commands to postgres backend while another process was running a transaction on the same connection. What I want is details about postgres backend mechanics when it comes to the situation like this.

Comment: What the application is doing, where it sends out-of-sync messages on the wire protocol, is totally broken. It's guaranteed to cause unpredictable problems. The protocol is somewhat robust, so you're not likely to get things like an unintended `commit`, but you're very likely to get transactions aborted or whole sessions disconnected suddenly. See the protocol documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-flow.html . It's a bit like asking "what happens if I rely on using undefined memory accesses". All sorts of things can happen. Don't do that.

Comment: All that PostgreSQL guarantees in this situation is that if you got a successful confirmation of a commit, it committed. Even then, if you mess up the wire protocol, you can't be totally sure that the `CommandComplete` message you got is for the `COMMIT` you issued, or some unrelated command a concurrent process snuck illegally onto the wire. You just can't do what you're doing and expect predictable results. Patch the driver so that method emits an immediate fatal error (or does proper sync) and submit the patch to upstream, please!

Comment: The `epgsql` driver implements the wire protocol directly. It doesn't `fork()`. When @Ivan says process, he means erlang-process and not OS-process. They are different beasts. In Erlang, you can have multiple e-processes accessing to the same connection and it is up to the driver to untangle this mess. My bet would be: not a Postgres problem, but mayhaps a driver problem.

Comment: @IGIVECRAPANSWERS Ah, so it's more multithreading than multiprocessing. Same issue - driver is doing something broken.